# How to show more information in QEMU

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu, busybox

I am trying to launch a Linux kernel by QEMU on Ubuntu by:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel: arch/i386/boot/bzImage -initrd ../busybox-1.19.4/rootfs.img -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init"
```

These are the [kernel logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J21M.png).

I cannot see the cause of failure. But when I adjust the window, the font size gets bigger. How can I debug this issue?

Comment: it can be virtually anything; kernel crashed

Answer (score 0):

First I see that you don't pass the architecture name with the option `-M` and `-m` to - specify the amount of memory.

You can debug your problem with GNU debugger (gdb).

But first you should enable the debug option when configuring QEMU so you should activate this option by:

```
./configure --enable-debug
```

Because by default builds with this flags "CFLAGS = -O2 -g" that block debugging.

After that, run:

```
gdb --args ./path/to your/executable_file_of_qemu -your_options
```

And you can run by the command run and step with s.